# DateTimeParseException by parsing a date string

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to parse a date string with Java `OffsetDateTime` but I get exceptions.

The string looks like this: `"20101217180000GMT+0800"`

My approach looks like this:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("20101217180000GMT+0800", DateTimeFormatter("yyyyMMddHHmmssz"));
```

I get:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: .... unparsed text found at index 17

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Yeah, double check your format String.

Comment: While you and I readily understand GMT+0800 as an offset of +08:00 from GMT, Java hasn’t got a pattern letter for this offset format. I think that [Andy Turner’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258403/5772882) is the right one.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two zone specifiers there:

- `GMT`
- `+0800`

If you print the substring of the time starting at index 17, the place where the error occurs, you get `+0800`, so it has consumed the `GMT` and doesn't know what to do with the rest.

I would suggest handling the `GMT` as a literal, i.e. surround it in single quotes, and use `Z` (or `X`, depending on how you'd want to handle GMT+0, if ever):

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss'GMT'Z
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/d401Xg)

Comment: @sziolkow add more 'z's.

Comment: OffsetDateTime.parse("20101217180000GMT+0800", DateTimeFormatter("yyyyMMddHHmmss'GMT'zzzz")); - same exception

Comment: @sziolkow glad you worked it out; added the extra zs into my answer.

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't solve my problem. I stil get the same exception

Comment: @sziolkow try capital Z.

Comment: After the edits this works nicely. Also works with `xx` instead of `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("20101217180000GMT+0800",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmsszx"));
```

This could work.
But I am thinking that zone and offset conflict.

Comment: It works and gives the desired `2010-12-17T18:00+08:00`. I don’t really like it. It parses GMT as a zone and +0800 as an offset. The two are in conflict. The parser doesn’t discover when what we ask for is an `OffsetDateTime`.